# Error de version con Xamarin.Android.Support

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocalización, xamarin.android

Actualmente quiero usar XF.material y xamarin.google.maps y estoy usando Android 10.0 para compilar el proyecto pero al juntar esas variables me salio el siguiente error:

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   NU1107  Se detectó un conflicto de versiones para Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Para resolver este problema, instale o haga referencia a Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 26.0.2 directamente en el proyecto PruebaGoogle.Android. 
 PruebaGoogle.Android -> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 26.0.2) 
 PruebaGoogle.Android -> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.1.0).    PruebaGoogle.Android    C:\ProyectosDesarrollo\PruebaGoogle\PruebaGoogle\PruebaGoogle.Android\PruebaGoogle.Android.csproj   1
```

Ademas de esos paquetes también estoy usando xam.plugin.geolocator, todos los paquetes en sus ultimas versiones.

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que instalar los paquetes nuget que te marca desde el ultimo en la linea que te marca hasta el primero. lo mas facil es que uses la consola de paquetes.

Herramientas -> Administrador de paquetes nuget -> Consola del administrador de paquetes.

```
install-package Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
install-package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement
install-package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps
install-package Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
```